# Assign and modify variables with percents (calculation)

Tags: python, variables, percentage

I am new to Python.
I am familiar with variables and assigning values to them.

But currently I got stuck with calculations below.

```
# current volume of a water reservoir (in cubic meters)
reservoir_volume = 4.445e8

# amount of rainfall from a storm (in cubic meters)
rainfall = 5e6

# decrease the rainfall by 10% to account for runoff
rainfall*=(10/100)

# add the rainfall to the reservoir_volume
rainfall += reservoir_volume

# increase reservoir_volume by 5% to account for storm water
# that flows into the reservoir in the days following the storm
reservoir_volume *= (5/100)

# decrease reservoir_volume by 5% to account for evaporation
reservoir_volume *= (5/100)

# subtract 2.5e5 cubic meters from reservoir_volume       
# to account for water that's piped to arid regions
reservoir_volume -= (2.5e5)

# print the new value of the reservoir_volume variable
print(reservoir_volume)
```

Can you give some insight what's incorrect?

Comment: @MichaelBianconi are you talking about the line that says subtract 2.5e5? I should increase it twice?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some basic math here. If you want to increase something by 5%, you need to use

```
volume += volume * 0.05
```

What you're doing (`volumn *= (5/100)`) is actually setting volume to 5% of it's current value. Also, make sure you use a negative sign when decreasing.

```py
# The current volume of a water reservoir (in cubic metres)
reservoir_volume = 4.445e8

# The amount of rainfall from a storm (in cubic metres)
rainfall = 5e6

# decrease the rainfall variable by 10% to account for runoff
rainfall -= reservoir_volume * (10/100)

# add the rainfall variable to the reservoir_volume variable
rainfall += reservoir_volume

# increase reservoir_volume by 5% to account for storm water that flows
# into the reservoir in the days following the storm
reservoir_volume += reservoir_volume * (5/100)

# decrease reservoir_volume by 5% to account for evaporation
reservoir_volume -= reservoir_volume * (5/100)

# subtract 2.5e5 cubic metres from reservoir_volume to account for water
# that's piped to arid regions.
reservoir_volume -= (2.5e5)

# print the new value of the reservoir_volume variable
print(reservoir_volume)
```

Comment: I edited the code to match the code example you added above. I get a Error. The solution list the answer as such:

Comment: # The current volume of a water reservoir (in cubic metres)
reservoir_volume = 4.445e8
# The amount of rainfall from a storm (in cubic metres)
rainfall = 5e6

# decrease the rainfall variable by 10% to account for runoff
rainfall *= .9

# add the rainfall variable to the reservoir_volume variable
reservoir_volume += rainfall

# increase reservoir_volume by 5% to account for stormwater that flows
# into the reservoir in the days following the storm
reservoir_volume *= 1.05

# decrease reservoir_volume by 5% to account for evaporation
reservoir_volume *= 0.95

Comment: Not really sure how they got to these answers. Thank you for your answers and assistance

Answer (score 0):

```
# The amount of rainfall from a storm (in cubic metres)
rainfall = 5e6

# decrease the rainfall variable by 10% to account for runoff
rainfall = rainfall*0.90

# add the rainfall variable to the reservoir_volume variable
reservoir_volume = reservoir_volume + rainfall


# increase reservoir_volume by 5% to account for stormwater that flows
# into the reservoir in the days following the storm
reservoir_volume = reservoir_volume*1.05

# decrease reservoir_volume by 5% to account for evaporation
reservoir_volume = reservoir_volume*0.95


# subtract 2.5e5 cubic metres from reservoir_volume to account for water
# that's piped to arid regions.
reservoir_volume = reservoir_volume - 2.5e5

# print the new value of the reservoir_volume variable
print(reservoir_volume)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Percentage change as factor or fraction

[Percentage increase and decrease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage#Percentage_increase_and_decrease) is not the most trivial in
mathematics.

- **decrease by 10%** means: multiply by `0.9` which is equivalent to the fraction `(100 - 10)/100 = 90/100`.
- **increase by 10%** means: multiply by `1.1` which is equivalent to the fraction `(100 + 10)/100 = 110/100`.
- **decrease by 5%** means: multiply by `0.95` which is equivalent to the fraction `(100 - 5)/100 = 95/100`.
- **increase by 5%** means: multiply by `1.05` which is equivalent to the fraction `(100 + 5)/100 = 105/100`.

### Issues: reconsider your fractions used to multiply

```py
# decrease the rainfall by 10% to account for runoff
rainfall *= (10/100)  # 10% decrease means factor (1 - 0.10) .. minus

# increase reservoir_volume by 5% to account for storm water
# that flows into the reservoir in the days following the storm
reservoir_volume *= (5/100)  # 5% increase means factor (1 + 0.05) .. plus

# decrease reservoir_volume by 5% to account for evaporation
reservoir_volume *= (5/100)  # 5% decrease means factor (1 - 0.05) .. minus
```

### Increase readability & reduce cognitive load

This entire calculation in your code is best reduced to a formula.
Therefore mathematicians use short symbol names (single character letters) and a lot of parentheses wrapping around expressions and so on.

Once you are familiar with the symbols and their meaning, you can grasp the whole calculation-process in a short one-liner, the formula.

The same way you could improve readability of your code. A side effect might be reduced cognitive load. I will give you some examples.

#### Express your comments as function

```
def evaporate(water_amount, percentage):
    return water_amount *= 1 - percentage # equals (1 - percent_points/100)

def inflow(water_amount, percentage):
    return water_amount *= 1 + percentage # equals (1 + percent_points/100)

def runoff(water_amount, percentage):
    return water_amount *= 1 - percentage # equals (1 - percent_points/100)
```

#### Given values as constants

Choose their name specific and include units in the name.

```py
# fix water amounts
reservoir_cubic_meters  = 4.445e8  # current volume (before rainfall)
rainfall_cubic_meters   = 5e6  # from storm
piped_away_cubic_meters = 2.5e5  # from reservoir to arid regions (after rainfall)

# percentages to increase / decrease
runoff_percent_points = 10 # rain decreasing by %
evaporation_percent_points = 10 # reservoir water decreasing by %
inflow_percent_points = 5  # rain storm_water increasing reservoir water by % after n days
```

#### Build the formula

```py
reservoir_cubic_meters  = 1  # initial volume 
rainfall_cubic_meters   = 5e6  # from storm

# used as global constant inside the function
piped_away_cubic_meters = 2.5e5  # to arid regions

# function = formula
after_rainfall(reservoir_cubic_meters, rainfall_cubic_meters):
    # 1. decrease the rainfall by 10% to account for runoff
    # 2. add the rainfall to the reservoir_volume
    # 3. increase reservoir_volume by 5% to account for storm water that flows into the reservoir in the days following the storm
    # 4. decrease reservoir_volume by 5% to account for evaporation
    # 5. subtract 2.5e5 cubic meters from reservoir_volume to account for water that's piped to arid regions
    
    return evaporate(inflow(reservoir_cubic_meters + runoff(rainfall_cubic_meters, 0.1)), 0.05), 0.05) - piped_away_cubic_meters

# naming: cubic_meters should be added ?!
reservoir_volume = after_rainfall(reservoir_cubic_meters, rainfall_cubic_meters)
```

**Note about representation of percentages:**
In my first version of this solution I expressed the percentages in `percent points` like `5` for 5%.
Now I changed the representation to fraction or ratio like `0.05` because its more common and reads easier. Even the constants are not necessarily needed. So I put in the literal percentages. The meaning can be derived from context of the formula and sub-functions inside.

Answer (score 0):

```
# The current volume of a water reservoir (in cubic metres)
reservoir_volume = 4.445e8
# The amount of rainfall from a storm (in cubic metres)
rainfall = 5e6

# decrease the rainfall variable by 10% to account for runoff
rainfall *= 1-0.1
# add the rainfall variable to the reservoir_volume variable
reservoir_volume += rainfall
# increase reservoir_volume by 5% to account for stormwater that flows
# into the reservoir in the days following the storm
reservoir_volume *= 1+0.05
# decrease reservoir_volume by 5% to account for evaporation
reservoir_volume *= 1-0.05
# subtract 2.5e5 cubic metres from reservoir_volume to account for water
# that's piped to arid regions.
reservoir_volume -= 2.5e5
# print the new value of the reservoir_volume variable
print(reservoir_volume)
```